# OCR android best opensource lib

Tags: android, ocr

I am lookibg for bets OCR lib for OCR which can detect the real business card .

Comment: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two  tesseract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tesseract-android-tools](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tesseract-android-tools) as open source lib .

There is a paid lib as well [ABBYY](http://ABBYY%20Mobile%20OCR%20Engine%20for%20Android)